# First Installation Problem with GNU GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, software-installation, gnu

When I try to install Ubuntu Desktop from a USB it gives me a GNU GRUB minimal command prompt instead of bringing me to the installation menu. I am trying to dual boot Windows 8.1 along side with this. And again this is before I have Ubuntu installed on my computer. I am running the new 2015 Dell XPS 13. I hope someone can help out.

Answer (score 0):

(breaking protocol here, comments are disabled for my account):

Please post the output of running `ls` at the command prompt. Also how did you produce the Ubuntu liveusb?

Also to search the drives run:

```
ls (hdX,partY)/dir
```

Where:

- `X` is the number of a hard drive
- `partY` is the second part of the partition label returned by the first `ls`
- `dir` optional path for further partition search

Hopefully you can find the vmlinuz and initrd files from this, if not, you probably have a faulty usb install.